# Using Amazon MQ as a broker relay for Spring Websockets + STOMP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-websocket, amazon-mq

Is it possible to use Amazon MQ as external broker for Spring + Websockets + STOMP? I'm trying with no luck. My config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
        .setRelayHost("my.amazon.stomp.endpoint").setRelayPort(61614)
        .setSystemLogin("xxxxxxxxx").setSystemPasscode("xxxxxxxxx");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws-myapp").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
  }
}
```

But when running the app, I get this from the logs (DEBUG):

```
2018-06-13 16:16:42.290 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a] REGISTERED
2018-06-13 16:16:42.291 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a] CONNECT: my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614
2018-06-13 16:16:42.398  INFO [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : CONNECTED: [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614]
2018-06-13 16:16:42.399 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] ACTIVE
2018-06-13 16:16:42.399 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection opened in session=_system_
2018-06-13 16:16:42.404 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] WRITE: 94B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 0a 61 63 63 65 70 74 2d 76 |CONNECT.accept-v|
|00000010| 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3a 31 2e 31 2c 31 2e 32 0a 6c |ersion:1.1,1.2.l|
|00000020| 6f 67 69 6e 3a 70 61 70 65 72 6c 65 73 73 0a 70 |ogin:xxxxxxxxx.p|
|00000030| 61 73 73 63 6f 64 65 3a 4d 38 7c 42 61 6e 41 47 |asscode:xxxxxxxx|
|00000040| 4c 2d 45 61 0a 68 65 61 72 74 2d 62 65 61 74 3a |xxxx.heart-beat:|
|00000050| 31 30 30 30 30 2c 31 30 30 30 30 0a 0a 00       |10000,10000...  |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2018-06-13 16:16:42.405 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] FLUSH
2018-06-13 16:16:42.406 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] USER_EVENT: reactor.io.net.impl.netty.NettyChannelHandlerBridge$ChannelInputSubscriberEvent@37c47287
2018-06-13 16:16:42.512 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] READ: 7B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 15 03 03 00 02 02 0a                            |.......         |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2018-06-13 16:16:42.513 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] READ COMPLETE
2018-06-13 16:16:42.514 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 - R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] READ COMPLETE
2018-06-13 16:16:42.623 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 ! R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] INACTIVE
2018-06-13 16:16:42.624 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection to broker closed in session _system_
2018-06-13 16:16:42.624 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Cleaning up connection state for session _system_
2018-06-13 16:16:42.624  INFO [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : CLOSED: [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 ! R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614]
2018-06-13 16:16:42.625  INFO [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : Failed to connect to reactor.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient$ReconnectingChannelListener$3@1ad2dfa9. Attempting reconnect in 5000ms.
2018-06-13 16:16:42.625 DEBUG [] 17743 --- [eactor-tcp-io-5] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : [id: 0xcd26491a, L:/my.local.ip:50392 ! R:my.amazon.stomp.endpoint:61614] UNREGISTERED
```

And it doesn't connect. Any ideas? It works perfectly when connecting to a local ActiveMQ instance, the difference is that locally it uses tcp://host vs Amazon which provides a stomp+ssl://host uri.

Anyway, I'm not including the protocol anyware. It seems that it connects but it doesn't receive any answer to the CONNECT message. I'm setting user and passcode I use to connect to the admin console. I am able to connect via javascript to the wss:// endpoint but I need to set it as external broker for a Spring Boot app.

Comment: I've also tryed the Openwire 61617 port with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, the issue was with enabling the SSL protocol. Here's how I did it:

1) I created a custom StompTcpFactory, to create a tcp client with SSL enabled:

```
/**
 * A TCP Client Factory to enable SSL connection
 */
public class StompTcpFactory implements NetStreams.TcpClientFactory<Message<byte[]>, Message<byte[]>> {

  private final Environment environment;
  private final EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup;
  private final boolean ssl;
  private final List<String> addresses;

  public StompTcpFactory(List<String> addresses, boolean ssl) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
    this.ssl = ssl;
    this.environment = new Environment(
        () -> new ReactorConfiguration(Collections.emptyList(), "sync", new Properties()));
    this.eventLoopGroup = Reactor2TcpClient.initEventLoopGroup();
  }

  @Override
  public Spec.TcpClientSpec<Message<byte[]>, Message<byte[]>> apply(
      Spec.TcpClientSpec<Message<byte[]>, Message<byte[]>> tcpClientSpec) {
    Supplier<InetSocketAddress> supplier = new InetSocketAddressSupplier(addresses);
    return tcpClientSpec.env(environment).options(new NettyClientSocketOptions().eventLoopGroup(eventLoopGroup))
        .codec(new Reactor2StompCodec(new StompEncoder(), new StompDecoder())).ssl(ssl ? new SslOptions() : null)
        .connect(supplier);
  }

}
```

Notice the .ssl call to set the flag to use ssl. Also I receive a list of addresses to config the endpoints and a boolean to be able to turn on and off ssl (for dev) .The InetSocketAddressSupplier was created to switch between the 2 addresses that Amazon gives you when working with a HA setup:

```
/**
 * Address supplier for failover connection
 */
@Slf4j
public class InetSocketAddressSupplier implements Supplier<InetSocketAddress> {

  private static int counter = 0;

  private final List<String> addresses;

  InetSocketAddressSupplier(List<String> addresses) {
    Assert.notNull(addresses, "addresses list cannot be null");
    Assert.isTrue(!addresses.isEmpty() && (addresses.size() == 2), "Addresses list must be of size 2");
    this.addresses = addresses;
  }

  @Override
  public InetSocketAddress get() {
    int serverIndex = counter % 2;
    counter++;
    String[] info = addresses.get(serverIndex).split(":");
    log.debug("Returning server {} {}:{} for connection", serverIndex, info[0], info[1]);
    return new InetSocketAddress(info[0], Integer.valueOf(info[1]));
  }

}
```

If you don't need the HA setup, you can simply create an inline supplier as it's shown in [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.18.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-handle-broker-relay-configure).

2) You can then configure your websocket endpoint to use this factory to create the client, and also set the user/password for the system and client connections:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Qualifier("websocket")
  private MessageBrokerProperties config;
  private InetSocketAddressSupplier supplier;

  public WebSocketConfiguration(MessageBrokerProperties config) {
    this.config = config;
    this.supplier = new InetSocketAddressSupplier(config.getAddresses());
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    InetSocketAddress address = supplier.get();
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost(address.getHostName()).setRelayPort(address.getPort())
        .setSystemLogin(config.getSystemLogin()).setSystemPasscode(config.getSystemPasscode())
        .setClientLogin(config.getClientLogin()).setClientPasscode(config.getClientPasscode())
        .setTcpClient(createTcpClient());
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  private TcpOperations<byte[]> createTcpClient() {
    return new Reactor2TcpClient<>(new StompTcpFactory(config.getAddresses(), config.isUseSSL()));
  }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I want to do similar thing with ActiveMQ Artemis (i.e. not AmazonMQ). I have an active/standby broker setup i.e. only one is active at a given time. Will your approach work? In my case I don't need SSL though (Needless to say that if this is the case, your contribution not only helps but should be included in Spring documentation IMO).

Comment: @kmandalas I figured out how the connection with ActiveMQ Artemis by configuring the connection as follow:

    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic")
      .setRelayHost(brokerRelayHost)
      .setRelayPort(brokerRelayPort)
      .setClientLogin(brokerRelayUser)
      .setClientPasscode(brokerRelayPass)
      .setSystemLogin(brokerRelayUser)
      .setSystemPasscode(brokerRelayPass)
      .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved-user")
      .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/log-user-registry");